# Disposable Registry: good pattern?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Imagine a:

```
public class Global : IDisposable 
{
    private static readonly List<IDisposable> Disposables = new List<IDisposable>();

    public void ApplicationStart()
    {
        var heavyLifter = new HeavyLifter();
        Disposables.Add(heavyLifter);
            // register a few more
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Disposables.ForEach(d => d.Dispose());
    }
}
```

I am somewhat inexperienced with IDisposable. Is this a viable pattern?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I want to register for disposal on creation of the resource and not have to remember to do it in another place 100 lines away. I think it is more refactor friendly not to spatter pieces of code all over my classes.
My uncertainty is, if there are possible issues that could lead to memory leaks, threadig issues and so on...

Comment: IDisposable is supposed to help you solve these kinds of issues, not create new ones. If you make your dispose methods thread safe, and clean up all unmanaged resources that are held by each individual object implementing dispose, I think you would have an ideal situation.

Comment: That`s why I want to apply it. My uncertainty stems more from static readonly than from pure IDisposable, or even more, about the combinantion of these. Assume, I know what IDisposable does and what it is for and how it is used generally.

Comment: Ah, now I think I'm seeing the light. You're centralizing all of your big resources in what is essentially a Singleton list. I don't know. If your only concern is that you won't remember to dispose some objects, I would write them so that they dispose themselves when they go out of scope. If they are all application-scope objects, then they should clean themselves up when the application exits. This gives you the freedom to instantiate them where they are needed, and organize the code the way you want: sensibly, using best practices.

Comment: So you mean, that if I keep an IDisposable object as a field in the Application, upon exit of the App, their Dispose method would be automatically called? That would make that list useless. Is the garbage collector that smart?

Comment: The garbage collector does not call `Dispose()` automatically, but it does call a finalizer, if you have put one in your class. See http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167 for more info on how this process works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ostensibly, this approach makes sense when you cannot make the disposal thread-safe (for example when talking to COM objects, which MUST be released on the same thread). However, in practice, you would find that this approach leads to objects living longer than they should.

I would strive to make the disposal thread safe, that way you can call `Dispose` from the finalizer and achieve truly automatic lifetime management. You have to be careful as might not be appropriate for some types of resources - like file or network handles, which might need tighter control. Otherwise, this is the **best** solution to this problem.

If the disposal HAS to be on the same thread then you are in a bit of a pickle. If the object needing disposing is in the model layer (as in business rules object) - it's quite likely it has layers of UI on top of, needing complex logic to dispose it (like events after a window is closed). It's a lose/lose situation and a choice between objects living forever (like your original solution) and complex disposal logic (which turns ugly pretty quickly).

Perhaps something to experiment with. You could separate the disposable resource into its own class and have the factory maintain a strong reference to it. The resource object maintains a weak reference back to business object. When the business object is finalized, `WeakReference` will return `null`, thus enabling you to make pass over the disposables and dump the ones that are no longer needed.

```
public class Global {
    private static readonly List<Resource> Disposables = new List<Resource>();

    public HeavyLifter GetHeavyLifter()
    {
        var resource = new HeavyLifterResource();
        var heavyLifter = new HeavyLifter(resource);
        resource.BusinessObject = heavyLifter;
        Disposables.Add(resource);
    }

    public void DisposeAll()
    {
        Disposables.ForEach(d => d.CleanUp());
    }
}

public abstract class Resource : IDisposable {

    WeakReference<object> m_BusinessObject;
    public WeakReference<object> BusinessObject {get;set;}

    public CleanUp() {
      if (!m_BusinessObject.IsAlive)
        Dispose();
    }
}

public HeavyLifter {
    public HeavyLifter (Disposable d) {
      m_resourceObj = d;
    }

    HeavyLifterResource m_resourceObj;
}

public class HeavyLifterResource :Resource {
    public void Dispose() {
      //disposal
    }
}
```

Let me again reiterate that the above approach is only appropriate for a certain class of objects. You wouldn't want to handle your network connections in such fuzzy way, but you can, for example, do this for business objects that need a network connection to dispose themselves. Even then, this is only appropriate when such connection is persistent through the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you're creating a component that will use (I assume) multiple resources that implement `IDisposable`, and you're simply looking for a way to maintain a list of `IDisposable` objects within your component and just iterate over the list rather than calling `Dispose` on each item by name, is that correct?

If so, there's nothing wrong with that. However, your list should not be `static`, it should be per-instance.

Comment: When I saw this I immediately thought base class with protected members.

Answer (score 1):

Well on one level IOC containers such as Unity can offer exactly this sort of functionality:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff663144.aspx

You delegate responsibility for creating objects to the IOC container, and can specify a LifetimeMangement option. This can include registering with the container for later disposal e.g. calling disposal on the container when an application shuts down, or when a form is closed.

For short lived objects you probably want to manage disposal yourself, but for longer lived objects an IOC type repository pattern with object disposal can work very well. Works well for me. :)

A good understanding of Disposal is always a good thing though.

Comment: Yes of course a container will do something like that, but I am not actually registering components here, that I will access later. These are applications, that will live on their own thread, doing their own thing during the lifetime of the application. In fact each of them might have their own container :)

Comment: Unity is pretty sophisticated and seems to offer something that will do exactly what you are trying to do. You can create child containers and it knows about threads too...

Comment: Unity provides options to create child containers and PerThreadLifetimeManager that may be of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perthreadlifetimemanager.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are working from the assumption that an outer class would have special knowledge of the lifetime of an object so that it call Dispose() at the right time.  That *rarely* works, only the client code knows when it is done with an object.

With your class as written, you achieve the exact opposite goal, you'll keep the objects alive much longer than necessary.  Not even the garbage collector could run the finalizer because you keep holding on to the object until some magic moment in time where *all* objects are ready to be disposed.  The usual term for this is "memory leak".  Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code implies that HeavyLifter implements IDisposable. So all you need to do is call its Dispose method in the Application_End eventhandler.

Answer (score 0):

A disposal registry may sometimes be useful as a concrete type, in cases where one knows that an object one is creating will have a lifetime that's tied to another object.  If a class is designed so that its creation can only take place wrapped within a particular factory method, and if one doesn't mind using `ThreadStatic` variables, one may even be able to replace:

```
DisposableThing Foo;  // At one point in the class
...
Foo  = new DisposableThing();  // In the constructor
...
DisposableThing.Dispose;  // In `Dispose(bool)`
```

with

```
DisposableThing = DisposeProtector.Register(new DisposableThing());
```

Taking care of declaration, initialization, and cleanup, all in the same line.

A very nice clean pattern, and one which even better in vb.net (no ThreadStatic variables required, and the disposal-registration method can be a member of the base type).  Probably a little too icky to be worthwhile in C#, but in vb.net it could be a nice pattern.  Note that if the constructor is properly wrapped, `Dispose` will get called on everything that was registered in its scope [but not a nested scope] when either `Dispose` is called on the class, or *the constructor throws*, the latter being a situation where it is otherwise difficult to avoid leaks.